# DRM Flash access and samsung smart tv

Tags: air, flex4, adobe, flash-builder, samsung-smart-tv

I would like to confirm if we can play DRM content with Adobe Access on Samsung Smart TV (2013- SDK 4.5).
So far, I have played back the DRM content successfully on Desktop and Android but I could not make it work on Samsung smart TV.
I have downgraded my AIR app to AIR version 2.6 ( it worked fine on my Desktop ) and installed it on the TV but when I tried to play, I got error 3307 (Internal Error). This error happened when I tried to create the DRM Metadata using _drmContentData = new DRMContentData(drmProtectedContent);

Could someone please confirm to me if I can play Adobe Access's DRM content on Samsung Smart TV?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After confirming with the tech guy from Samsung, it is not possible to use Adobe Access with Samsung Smart TV at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The RTMPE spec is supported, so yes, you can do DRM on streaming video. http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/Spec

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your answer but after asking the Technical people in Samsung forum, it is not possible for us to Adobe Access with Samsung Smart TV. PlayReady with SmoothStreaming is the best choice at the moment.